# CSS Grid: how to make each column has the same width regardless of content

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <style>
        #app {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;

            justify-content: start;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;

            min-height: 100vh !important;


            width: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;


            background-color: rebeccapurple;

            color: white;
        }

        #content  {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: start;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #elements  {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;

            grid-column-gap: 3em;
            grid-row-gap: 3em;

            overflow: auto;
            max-width: 70%;
            min-width: 70%;
        }

        .element  {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: start;
            align-items: center;


            background-color: orange;
        }

        .element img  {
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;

            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <div id="content">

        <div id="elements">

            <div class="element">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-04/220428-dog-breeds-mb-1019-95b354.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="element-content">
                    <div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do e
                     </div>

                    <div>
                        Other content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="element">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-04/220428-dog-breeds-mb-1019-95b354.jpg"/>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="element-content">
                    <div>

                    </div>

                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="element">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-04/220428-dog-breeds-mb-1019-95b354.jpg"/>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="element-content">
                    <div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

                    </div>

                    <div>
                        Other content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="element">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-04/220428-dog-breeds-mb-1019-95b354.jpg"/>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="element-content">
                    <div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        Other content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="element">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-04/220428-dog-breeds-mb-1019-95b354.jpg"/>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="element-content">
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="element">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-04/220428-dog-breeds-mb-1019-95b354.jpg"/>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="element-content">
                    <div>
                     </div>

                    <div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="element">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-04/220428-dog-breeds-mb-1019-95b354.jpg"/>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="element-content">
                    <div>
                     </div>

                    <div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows:

[image]

As can be seen, not all columns have the same width.

How do I fix it so that all columns have exactly the same width, even when the `element-content` is empty?

Comment: set a width on the columns

Comment: 1fr instead of auto

Answer (score 0):

Have the "element" class have a fixed width, meaning not by precentage but by px,pt etc.

Comment: percentage would be fine too